# Obtener el último número

Tags: r, dataframe

¿Cómo obtengo el último número entero de cada linea?

```
df <- data.frame( col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                  col2 = c("300 ww 1.4/-: Tb  6b 2170","erty 300 ww 1.4",
                         "sss 2 ss 34"," verde rojo (8383)","er:.56 tomate.455"))
```

```
col1                      col2
1    1 300 ww 1.4/-: Tb  6b 2170
2    2           erty 300 ww 1.4
3    3               sss 2 ss 34
4    4         verde rojo (8383)
5    5        er:.56 tomate.455
```

El resultado esperado sería

```
col1                      col2           col3
1    1 300 ww 1.4/-: Tb  6b 2170          2170
2    2           erty 300 ww 1.4          (ninguno pq tiene decimal y se busca número entero)
3    3               sss 2 ss 34          34
4    4         verde rojo (8383)          (ninguno pq va entre paréntesis)
5    5        er:.56 tomate.455           455 (aunque hay un . delante si es el último número)
```

Agradecería toda ayuda posible.

Comment: Lógicamente  los comentarios en col3 no tienen que aparecer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que entiendo por el ejemplo, es que estás mirando siempre la última "palabra" de cada cadena. Una forma sencilla, con R base, es separar cada palabra por espacio, intentar convertir la cadena a un número y por último verificar  si dicho numero es un entero:

```
sapply(strsplit(df$col2, "\\D\\.| "),
       FUN=function(x) { 
         num <- tryCatch(as.numeric(rev(x)[1]),  warning = function(x) NA)
         ifelse(num == as.integer(num), num, NA)
       }
) -> df$col2num
```

El patrón de separación: `"\\D\\.| "`, es: 1) todo punto que no venga de un número y 2) el espacio

Comment: Muchas gracias. Falla en el último ejemplo (tomate.455) pero puedo hacer una transformación previa y cambiar el punto por un espacio. O sea que fantástico.

Comment: Es cierto, se me escapó el caso, pero podemos aprovechar que el separador puede ser una expresión regular para indicar que separe por espacio y el .

Comment: Fantástico. Creo que te faltó cerrar comillas en el ejemplo, "\\D\\.| "   Lo digo por si alguien más intenta reproducirlo. Tengo otra duda, no sé si ponerlo aquí o como pregunta aparte. Usando la misma estructura del código no consigo eliminar el numero de forma que me quede la frase completa sin el último número. Solo me sale para la primera linea pero no se reproduce para el resto del bucle.

Comment: Gracias, en cuanto a tu duda, podrías usar la mismas función para saber si efectivamente la última palabra es un número válido, si lo es puedes quedarte con el resto de las "palabras" que acabamos de "esplitear"  con `head(x, -1)`, cualquier cosa puedes hacer una nueva pregunta y lo vemos.

Comment: Con head(x, -1) solo consigo sacar la primera palabra de cada frase, busco la frase al completo. Algo estoy haciendo mal. Voy a ponerlo como otra pregunta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: `head(x, -1) ` te debería retornar todos los valores menos el último: `head(c(1,2,3), -1) == c(1,2)`