# Eliminar último número de cada línea

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

[Viene de aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/393091/obtener-el-%C3%BAltimo-n%C3%BAmero/393329?noredirect=1#comment704438_393329)

¿Cómo elimino el último número de cada frase cuando el número es entero?

```
df <- data.frame( col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                  col2 = c("pepe marta juan 2170","300 ww 1.4",
                           "verde 85"," verde (8383)","amarillo rojo tomate.455"))
df$col2<-as.character(df$col2)
```

```
  col1                     col2
1    1     pepe marta juan 2170
2    2               300 ww 1.4
3    3                 verde 85
4    4             verde (8383)
5    5 amarillo rojo tomate.455
```

El resultado buscado sería

```
 col1                     col2     col3
1    1     pepe marta juan 2170    pepe marta juan
2    2               300 ww 1.4    300 ww 1.4
3    3                 verde 85    verde
4    4             verde (8383)    verde (8383)
5    5 amarillo rojo tomate.455    amarillo rojo tomate.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El requerimiento final sería, obtener el último número y las frase que no incluye dicho numero. Podemos hacer algo parecido a tu otra pregunta para determina que es y que no es un número válido, cuando lo sea simplemente recortamos la cadena original, para quedarnos con las frase sin el número:

```
lapply(1:nrow(df),
       FUN=function(x) {
         frase <- df$col2[x]
         words <-  strsplit(frase, "\\D\\.| ")
         last_word <- rev(words[[1]])[1]
         # cat(last_word, sep='\n')
         num <- tryCatch(as.numeric(last_word),  warning = function(x) NA)
         if (!is.na(num) & num == as.integer(num)) {
           frase <- substr(frase,  1, nchar(frase) - nchar(last_word))
         } else {
           num <- NA
         }
         data.frame(frase=frase, num=num)
       }
) -> lista

cbind(df,
      do.call(rbind,  lista)
)
```

El resultado final, sería el `df` original con dos nuevas columnas:

```
  col1                      col2                 frase  num
1    1 300 ww 1.4/-: Tb  6b 2170 300 ww 1.4/-: Tb  6b  2170
2    2           erty 300 ww 1.4       erty 300 ww 1.4   NA
3    3               sss 2 ss 34             sss 2 ss    34
4    4         verde rojo (8383)     verde rojo (8383)   NA
5    5         er:.56 tomate.455        er:.56 tomate.  455
```

Comment: Muy bueno, hay mucho que analizar y aprender de ese código. Muchas gracias.